# Switch statement using a union in C, got me into problems, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c, switch-statement, unions

I'm almost done with my assignment where I was supposed to build a program where the user interacts with a warehouseprogram, where you can delete, add, edit... However in my `event_loop` function, no matter what input I type to choose from the menu goes to default in my switch statement. I'm using a uniontype answer_t in my ask_question_menu, so maybe it has something to do with the return from that function that I want to be a single char. Can someone tell me what the heck is going on here?

Very thankful for help!

```
typedef union {
    int   i;
    float f;
    char *s;
    char d;
} answer_t;

char ask_question_menu(char *question){
    answer_t answer = ask_question(question, correct_input, (convert_func) toupper);
    return answer.d;
}
//my general function for user input follows here...
answer_t ask_question(char *question, check_func check, convert_func convert)
{
    int buffersize = 50;
    char buffer[buffersize];

    do
        {
            printf("%s\n", question);
            read_string(buffer, buffersize);
        }

    while(check(buffer)==false);

    answer_t result = convert(buffer);

    return result;
}

int event_loop(item_t *db, int *db_size)
{
    while(true){
        char choise = ask_question_menu(" [L]ägga till en vara\n [T]a bort en vara\n [R]edigera en vara\n Ån[g]ra senaste ändringen\n Lista [h]ela varukatalogen\n [A]vsluta\n");

        switch(choise)
            {
            case 'L':
                add_item_to_db(db, db_size);
                break;
            case 'T':
                remove_item_from_db(db, db_size);
                break;
            case 'R':
                edit_db(db, *db_size);
                break;
            case 'G':
                printf("Not yet implemented\n");
                break;
            case 'H':
                list_db(db, *db_size);
            case 'A':
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong input\n");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing that will get you to problems is your code formatting.

Comment: `case 'H':` is missing `break` statement ?

Comment: `(convert_func)toupper` probably leads to undefined behaviour. To confirm this please show the definition of `convert_func`

Comment: What is `convert_func`?  That you seem to need to explicitly cast `toupper` is a strong indication that you're dong something wrong.

Comment: `check(buffer)==false` is better written as `! check(buffer)`. Don't compare boolean values for equality to `false` or `true`. Just test them directly. That's what boolean values are for, after all.

Answer (score 1):

When `convert` points to `toupper()`, this line ...

```
answer_t result = convert(buffer);
```

... definitely produces undefined behavior, because `toupper()` takes a parameter of type `int` and returns an `int`, but you are passing a `char *` and assuming that the return value is an `answer_t`.  If you prefer, you can say that it is the cast of `toupper` to `convert_func` that is ultimately responsible for this UB.

If you need a function that returns an `answer_t`, then you'll need to wrap `toupper()`.  It's unclear exactly what form a `convert_func` is supposed to have, but this would be compatible with the way you are trying to use it:

```
answer_t toupper_wrap(char *buffer) {
    return (answer_t) { .d = toupper(*buffer) };
}
```

Pass a pointer to that instead of a pointer directly to `toupper()`.

Comment: I see, never thought that toupper would be of type int, rookie-mistake. But now i used your magical function and it completed my program so thanks a lot man, really appreciate it!